# F# transaction management

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have been thinking of implementing an e-payment system in F#. One critical requirement is transaction management.

I used the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) with Dapper and it worked well. I could use [Tranq](https://github.com/nakamura-to/Tranq) to manage DB transactions, but would like to use something like TransactionScope to manage online operations.

Relatively new to F#, I don't know if there is anything that is equivalent to

```cs
using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
{
    ...//operations
    trans.Complete();
}
```

If the line-to-line translating from C# to F# approach is wrong, then is there any more "functional way" of managing transactions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

F# has a similar `using` block to C#.

```
using (new Thing()) (fun x -> x.DoStuff ... )
```

[But there is also a `use` binding in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233240.aspx), which works just like `let` except it calls `Dispose` when the object goes out of scope. It's not too hard to make a new type that wraps `TransactionScope` and calls `Complete` when it's disposed if it hasn't been rolled back by code...

It would also be possible to make a [workflow builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) take care of transactions.

However, you might be better off using a database layer such as Entity Framework which handles your transactional needs.